# Java parsing multipart/form-data from file

Tags: java, parsing, file-upload, multipartform-data

My goal is to parse following multipart/form-data, stored in file. How can I do this ? I've found e.g. Apache Common FileUpload library but it only seems to support when fileupload is coming from httpservlet request.

```
--2cVU8PK7CHQWWSrkKrygDDisopnoT4CSwoz_b
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="multipart.xml"
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml>
<data>some data sent via post multipart</data>
</xml>
--2cVU8PK7CHQWWSrkKrygDDisopnoT4CSwoz_b--
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem. I solved it by creating a 'dummy' ServletRequest and then passing this on to Commons File Upload.

I have uploaded the code for this to GitHub:

[delight-fileupload](https://github.com/javadelight/delight-fileupload)

Comment: i have used the delight - fileupload jar as per GITHUB code base, and it is not working me.. it doesn't parse the data at all and through exceptions

Comment: This library has successfully been used in production applications. Could you file an issue in https://github.com/javadelight/delight-fileupload/issues with your example that is failing?